what are all documents needed to submit a provisional application?

The written disclosure (PDF)
The drawings (PDF)
The cover sheet (PDF)

I've just submitted the Customer Number request form and the Patent Electronic System Verification Form.
Am I missing something?

The documents are a complete list but note the system for submitting it is not particularly user friendly. You can get wrong page size, imbedded font issues, etc with the PDFs.
If there are math or chemical expressions in an original Word doc, the PDF may or not be rendered correctly.

Do you mean that the 3 documents that I listed is complete? Actually, the specifications will be submitted in word format, I believe.

Yes the document list seems complete.
